# Thunderbird with Lightning and Google provider no longer working?

Tags: thunderbird, calendar, google-calendar, lightning

I'm using Thunderbird 31.1.12, Lightning 3.3.1 with Provider for Google Calendar 1.0.1 in Ubuntu 14.04

When I try to add my google calendars, I select 'Create new calendar'> 'On my Network'> and select 'Google', I find that the location field disappears as soon as I select 'Google'.

In the next window it asks me to 'pick an existing session or a new session or enter your email address to create a new session'. This is not how it usually  functions, (or indeed how it functions on other platforms). Even if I enter my google address at that stage it doesn't successfully find my online calendar.

If anyone can shed any light on this I would be grateful as it's very frustrating at the moment.

Best wishes and thanks!

Comment: Do you mean "On THE Network" ? Also, how did you install Lightning?  Did you add it from the Addons Manager in Thunderbird, or did you install it using "sudo apt-get install xul-ext-lightning" ?

Comment: Yes, apologies I meant on 'On The Network'.

Comment: I added Lightning via the add ons manager in Thunderbird, but perhaps significantly, 'Google Provider for Lightning' would not download via the add on manager, so I downloaded from the Mozilla site and installed from file.

Answer (score 1):

by chance I did that last night:

-delete first the old "network calendar(s)"

-choose new calendar

-choose google

-insert your email adress and your password

a window opens showing you your google calendars

-choose the calendars you want to syncronize with Lightning

Done

Comment: Strangely this has worked for me today when it wouldn't yesterday; no calendars appeared after entering my email address yesterday, today they have. Under the old method where you had to provide the location of your calendar, and add each manually, you had the option to make the calendar available offline which I preferred. This new way the calendars are only available if you have an internet connection.